# find all possible ways to build a specific string

Tags: python, permutation

I am trying to generate all possible ways to build a target string from source string in Python.

- source: cattcat
- target: cat

output: 5

- (cat)tcat
- (ca)t(t)cat
- (ca)ttca(t)
- (c)attc(at)
- catt(cat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
def get_combos(d, s, i = 0, c = []):
   if (r:=''.join(b for _, b in c)) == s:
      yield c
   elif d:
     if s.startswith(r+d[0]):
        yield from get_combos(d[1:], s, i = i+1, c=c+[(i, d[0])])
     yield from get_combos(d[1:], s, i = i+1, c=c)

print(list(get_combos('cattcat', 'cat')))
```

Output:

```
[[(0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (2, 't')], 
 [(0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (3, 't')], 
 [(0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (6, 't')], 
 [(0, 'c'), (5, 'a'), (6, 't')], 
 [(4, 'c'), (5, 'a'), (6, 't')]]
```

For the purposes of demonstration, each character's index in the original source string is included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
Simple String , array and Dictionary 
    s = "cattcat"
    t = "cat"
    n = len(s)
    nt = len(t)
    a={}
    for i  in range(0,nt):
        c = t[i]
        for j in range(0,n):
            if (s[j] == c):
                if c in a:
                    try:
                        a[c].append(j+1)
                    except:
                        a[c]=[a[c],j+1]
                else:
                    a[c]=j+1
    print(a)
    for z in range(0,len(a['c'])):
        for y in range(0,len(a['a'])):
            for x in range(0,len(a['t'])):
                if(a['c'][z]<=a['a'][y]<=a['t'][x]):
                    print(a['c'][z],a['a'][y],a['t'][x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all possible combinations using itertools.combinations. Using zip, you can track not just the characters but also their positions. The whole process becomes a single list comprehension exercise, which should be fairly efficient.

```
from itertools import combinations
src='cattcat'
trg='cat'

comb_lst=[idx for el, idx in zip(
combinations(src,len(trg)),
combinations(range(len(src)),len(trg))
) if ''.join(el)==trg]

print(comb_lst)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 6), (0, 5, 6), (4, 5, 6)]
```